# LeaveOneOutEncoder in sklearn.pipeline

Tags: python, pipeline

I make a pipeline with LeaveOneOutEncoder. Of course I use a toy example. [Leave One Out](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/leaveoneout.html) is for transforming categorical variables

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import sklearn
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from category_encoders import  LeaveOneOutEncoder
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

df= pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'a': ['a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b' ], 'b': [5,5,3,4,8,6,7,3],})

class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key
def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self
def transform(self, data_dict):
    return data_dict[self.key]

class MyLEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def transform(self, X, **fit_params):
    enc = LeaveOneOutEncoder()
    encc = enc.fit(np.asarray(X), y)
    enc_data = encc.transform(np.asarray(X))
    return enc_data
def fit_transform(self, X,y=None,  **fit_params):
    self.fit(X,y,  **fit_params)
    return self.transform(X)
def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
    return self


X = df[['a', 'b']]
y = df['y']

regressor = linear_model.SGDRegressor()

pipeline = Pipeline([

    # Use FeatureUnion to combine the features
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[


             # categorical
            ('categorical', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='a')),
                ('one_hot', MyLEncoder())

            ])),
             # year

        ])),
    # Use a regression
    ('model_fitting', linear_model.SGDRegressor()),
])

pipeline.fit(X, y)
pipeline.predict(X)
```

That's ALL correct whan I use it on train and test data! But when i try predict a new data I get an erorr

```
pipeline.predict(pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [3, 8], 'a': ['a', 'b' ], 'b': [3, 6],}))
```

help to find a mistake! The mistake must be simple but my eyes are swimming. And the problem must be in class MyLEncoder. What must I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
encc = enc.fit(np.asarray(X), y)
```

in the `transform()` method of `MyLEncoder`.

So there are a couple of problems here:

1) Your `LeaveOneOutEncoder` only remembers the last data passed to the `transform` of `MyLEncoder` and forgets the previous data.

2) During fitting `LeaveOneOutEncoder` requires the `y` to be present. But that would not be present during prediction, when `MyLEncoder` `transform()` is called.

3) Currently your line:

```
pipeline.predict(X)
```

is working just by luck because your `X`  is same, and when the `MyLEncoder` `transform()` is called, you have already defined `y` so it is used. But thats just wrong.

4) An unrelated thing (may not call this an error). When you do this:

```
pipeline.predict(pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [3, 8], 'a': ['a', 'b' ], 'b': [3, 6],}))
```

`pipeline.predict()` requires `X` only, not `y`. But you are sending `y` also in that. Currently its not a problem because in the pipeline you are using only the `a` column and throwing away all information, but maybe in complex setups, this may slip through and data present in `y` column will be used as features (`X` data) which will then give you wrong results.

To solve this, change your `MyLEncoder` as:

```
class MyLEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    # Save the enc during fitting
    def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
        enc = LeaveOneOutEncoder()
        self.enc = enc.fit(np.asarray(X), y)

        return self

    # Here, no new learning should be done, so never call fit() inside this
    # Only use the already saved enc here
    def transform(self, X, **fit_params):

        enc_data = self.enc.transform(np.asarray(X))
        return enc_data

    # No need to define this function, if you are not doing any optimisation in it.
    # It will be automatically inherited from TransformerMixin
    # I have only kept it here, because you kept it.
    def fit_transform(self, X,y=None, **fit_params):
        self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X)
```

Now when you do this:

```
pipeline.predict(pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [3, 8], 'a': ['a', 'b' ], 'b': [3, 6],}))
```

You will not get any error, but still as said in point 4, I would like you to do something like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'y': [3, 8], 'a': ['a', 'b' ], 'b': [3, 6],})

new_X = new_df[['a', 'b']]
new_y = new_df['y']

pipeline.predict(new_X)
```

so that the X used in training time and new_X used in predicting time appear same.

Answer (score 1):

I've done as below

```
lb = df['a']
class MyLEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def transform(self, X, **fit_params):
    enc = LeaveOneOutEncoder()
    encc = enc.fit(np.asarray(lb), y)
    enc_data = encc.transform(np.asarray(X))

    return enc_data

def fit_transform(self, X,y=None,  **fit_params):
    self.fit(X,y,  **fit_params)
    return self.transform(X)

def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
    return self
```

So I changed `X` in row `encc = enc.fit(np.asarray(lb), y)` on `lb`.